# Laravel 5 CMS making?

Tags: php, laravel, content-management-system, laravel-5

I'm trying to build a simple CMS with Laravel 5 and I'm stopped at this:

[image: Category forums duplicating]

Category titles are ok, but inside same (dublicating forums)? Why is it? My code:

```
@extends('layouts.main')
@section('content')
@foreach($categories as $category)
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading">{{ $category->title }}</div>
  <div class="panel-body">
      <table class="table">
      <tbody>
      @foreach($forums as $forum)
      <tr>
          <th scope="row">{{ $forum->id }}</th>
          <td><a href="{{ generateForumURL($forum->seo_name, $forum->id) }}">{{ $forum->name }}</a></td>
          <td>{{ $forum->topics }}</td>
          <td>{{ $forum->posts }}</td>
      </tr>
      @endforeach
    </tbody>
   </table>
  </div>
</div>
@endforeach
@stop
```

In routes:

```
Route::get('', function()
{
        $forums = DB::table('forums')
                ->select()
                ->get();

        $categories = DB::table('categories')
                ->select()
                ->get();

    return View::make('home', compact('forums', 'categories'));
});
```

In PhpMyAdmin:

categories:
[image: categories table]

forums:
[image: forums table]

I know that I didn't do something, but I don't know what, I'm a newbie with Laravel. P.S I'm not good in english, sorry for my bad language :) Thanks so much in advance ;)

**Shortly:** I wan't to show the forum in that category which is written in `in_category` row. Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking.

Comment: @Jamesking56 as you see now in two categories prints same forums, but I wan't to print in one category one forums, in other category other forums.. I have tables in PhpMyAdmin:
`in_category` and every category has unique id. So I wan't to print x forum in x category via id

Comment: I doubt whether you understand me :D

Comment: I understand you now. you need to define a relationship between a category and a forum inside of a category. You can do this using joins via the query builder or I suggest you define [eloquent models](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent) and [define an eloquent relationship](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent-relationships) as this will allow you to do `$category->forums` to get forums inside a given category.

Comment: @Jamesking56 thanks so much. Maybe can you try to write code for me? :((

Comment: @Jamesking56 Please :(

Comment: see my elaborate answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK here goes an elaborate answer.

In Laravel, you can use Eloquent models as a way of creating entities within your application. In this case, I think that eloquent models will be the best thing to do.

Firstly, create a new model as follows `app/Category.php`:

```
<?php
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Category extends Model {

    protected $table = "categories";

    public $timestamps = false;

    public function forums() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Forum', 'in_category');
    }

}
```

Then create another model as follows `app/Forum.php`:

```
<?php
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Forum extends Model {

    protected $table = "forums";

    public $timestamps = false;

    public function category() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Category');
    }

}
```

Once you have done this, you can now modify your route as follows:

```
<?php
use App\Category;

Route::get('', function()
{
    $categories = Category::all();

    return View::make('home', compact('categories'));
});
```

and your view as follows:

```
@extends('layouts.main')
@section('content')
@foreach($categories as $category)
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">{{ $category->title }}</div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <table class="table">
            <tbody>
            @foreach($category->forums as $forum)
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">{{ $forum->id }}</th>
                <td><a href="{{ generateForumURL($forum->seo_name, $forum->id) }}">{{ $forum->name }}</a></td>
                <td>{{ $forum->topics }}</td>
                <td>{{ $forum->posts }}</td>
            </tr>
            @endforeach
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
@endforeach
@stop
```

This should resolve your issue by only showing the forums for the category within the category.

Comment: `Class 'Category' not found` maybe I must write something in composer?

Comment: Have you put the two model classes inside the `app/` directory?

Comment: I've created maually, created .txt file, written text, then saved as .php file

Comment: Yes but are they inside the `app` folder?

Comment: Yes, they are in app folder

Comment: Have you added `use App\Category;` to the top of your `routes.php` file (underneath `<?php`)?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85123/discussion-between-evaldas888-and-jamesking56).